# Ruby create Tempfile to save CSV row and assign it to database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, csv

I have very complex problem here.

I'm exporting two spreadsheets using CSV library and there are one to many association between the two sheets

The problem is i need to save the foreign key for Result record based on a value in a specific row and then save the rest of the data from the next row
so here an example

```
 1023115111      | SUMMARY   |  1.5 | 2 | 2.5

 8/16/2017 23:00 |     1.3   |  1.5 | 2 | 2.5

 1023201         | SUMMARY   |  1.9 | 2 | 2.1

 8/16/2017 7:10  |    1.76   |  1.9 | 2 | 2.1

 8/16/2017 15:00 |    1.76   |  1.9 | 2 | 2.1
```

Here are the problem

i need to take the first cell where the summary row exists and compare it find the machine which it is "mid" equal to this value

then skip the whole row and save the "Result" to new record where the machine_id equal to this value

i will try to make it more clear

```
@mid = row(0)     

@machine = Machine.where(mid: @mid)
```

then

```
Result.create(line: line, min: min, exps: real, max: max, 
 ideal: mean, time: time, machine_id: @machine.id  )
```

This is my Result Model

```
require 'csv'    
require 'tempfile'    
require 'fileutils'    
class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :machine
def self.assign_row(row)     
   line, b, time, real, min, mean, max = row
   Result.create(line: line, min: min, exps: real, max: max, ideal: mean, time: time  )    
      end    

def self.import(file)    
   CSV.foreach(file.path, encoding: 'iso-8859-1:utf-8', skip_blanks: true) do |row|    
  next if row[3] =~ /SUMMARY/       
  next if row.all?(&:nil?)       
  result = Result.assign_row(row)       
    end     
   end     
  end
```

this is my Machine Model

```
require 'csv'    
class Machine < ActiveRecord::Base    
validates_uniqueness_of  :name    
has_many :results    
def self.assign_row(row)
 a, b, c = row
 if row[2].nil?
  puts 'na'
 else

 @mid = c[0..2]
 @name = c[5..-1]
end
machine = Machine.find_by(name: c)
Machine.create(name: @name, mid: @mid) if machine.blank?
end

def self.import(file)    
     CSV.foreach(file.path, encoding: 'iso-8859-1:utf-8', skip_blanks: true) do |row|    
 machine = Machine.assign_row(row)    
   end    
 end    
end
```

Result Migration

```
class CreateResults < ActiveRecord::Migration     
def change      
create_table :results do |t|      
  t.string :min      
  t.string :max      
  t.string :time     
  t.string :exps     
  t.references :machine, index: true, foreign_key: true     
  t.string :line     
  t.string :ideal     

  t.timestamps null: false     
     end     
   end     
 end
```

Machine Migration

```
 class CreateMachines < ActiveRecord::Migration     
 def change     
 create_table :machines do |t|     
  t.string :name     
  t.string :mid     

  t.timestamps null: false     
end     
add_index :machines, :mid     
end     
end
```

Machine controller import

```
 def import     
 count = Machine.import(params[:file])     
 redirect_to machines_path, notice: "file imported successfully!"     
 end
```

Result controller import

```
 def import      
 count = Result.import params[:file]     
 redirect_to results_path, notice: "file imported successfully!"     
 end
```

I thought perhaps i could save the CSV to Tempfile then assign the value to the database but the skip condition will override it?

another solution came into my mind is `has_many_through` but i don`t really know it will work or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure something out

it is not perfect yet but it imported some important data

Here is the modified Result Model code

```
require 'csv'     
class Result < ActiveRecord::Base     
belongs_to :machine     
def self.assign_row(row)    
    line, b, time, real, min, mean, max = row    
    if row[3] =~ /SUMMARY/      
   @midr = row[2].slice(1,3)      
   @mach = Machine.where(:mid => @midr).first      
   @result = Result.create(midr: time, machine_id: @mach.id  )     
  else      
   line, b, time, real, min, mean, max = row      
   @result.update( exps: real, max: max, ideal: mean, time: time  )     
      end      
  end     
 def self.import(file)     
 CSV.foreach(file.path, encoding: 'iso-8859-1:utf-8', skip_blanks: true) do |row|       
next if row.all?(&:nil?)      
result = Result.assign_row(row)     
       end     
  end     
end
```